# I want to travel to the Schengen area for business and take my family with me. Can we apply for a visa together?

Tags: schengen, family, applications, schengen-visas

I am about to Travel to Germany on Business visa. I want my family to accompany me, and we wish to tour around for a week or so. The total head count is three people. My intent is to go there and possibly apply for a work permit from Germany.

Should I apply for Business+Tourist visas (for family) together OR should I first get the Business VISA, then post getting it apply for the Tourist visa's? Is there are any preference from any of your experience, or does it not matter?

Comment: You should ask on Expatriates.SE regarding the work permit. There is a jobseeker's visa, §18c, and coming on a business visa with the *intent* to stay risks a refusal.

Comment: @o.m. OP doesn't mention he will stay for a long time

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/86151/which-category-of-visa-do-a-spouse-and-child-require-when-accompaning-an-indian

Comment: Schengen group visas are subject to a minimum head count (5) which is not given in your question. Unclear.

Comment: @GayotFow Totally three people. Me on Business, and my wife +daughter on tourist VISA, accompanying me. As I said, intent is to go there and possibly apply for a work permit.  

Jonathan - Thanks for your pointer. Helpful, but I just need to know, if I should make the application together, or tourist post getting Business VISA. Thanks!

Comment: You can submit your applications together. Their application's cover letter can state that they will accompany you. Alternatively you can wait till your visa is issued, then attach a copy with their application. I don't think there should be much of a difference either way  because same consulate will handle the applications of you and your family.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be up to you to decide whether to apply for a visa for yourself and, separately, for your wife and child, or to apply at the same time.

If you have a business reason to visit Germany and want your wife and child to accompany you, do as you say: apply for a business visa, and tourists visas for your family members.

Done separately or together doesn't matter: you will apply through the same consulate, and the information on your visas entered into the [Visa Information System (VIS)](http://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-information-system_en) which allows Schengen States to exchange visa data. It processes data and decisions relating to applications for short-stay visas to visit, or to transit through, the Schengen Area.

If, as you comment, your intent is to find work, then, rather than risk a refusal of one, or all, of your visa applications, a safer plan might be to go the route that allows you to work and live there.

Germany has online tools and information which streamline and facilitate this process, and [Make It In Germany*](http://www.make-it-in-germany.com/en/for-qualified-professionals/working) has everything you need, be it as an individual or as a business.

*Under the auspices of the Federal Ministry for Economic Affairs and Energy, the Federal Ministry of Labour and Social Affairs, Bundesagentur für Arbeit (the Federal Employment Agency, the largest provider of labour market services in Germany).