# Taking wife on Standard Visitor visa while I am applying for a UK business visa

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, business-travel, spouses, standard-visitor-visas

I am going to the UK for business meetings for one month. I have an invitation letter from our UK office and I want my wife and child to accompany my.

How should I apply for their visas? All of us are Indian citezens.

Should I write a letter to support their visa application?

Should I mention in my wife's and son's application that they will be staying with me in the UK and I will bear their all other expenses?

Should I write a statement to my wife to support the above mentioned?

Should I submit all three applications together?

Comment: Related (dupe?): https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39542/what-visa-does-my-wife-need-to-travel-to-the-uk-with-me-if-im-going-there-on-a?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If you're only coming for meetings (so, no paid work), you don't need a business visa. You can apply for a standard visitor visa along with your family.
You should simply tell the truth, you're going for some business meetings, and then tourism with your family.
https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/work/six_months_or_less
As long as you fill all the requisites (accommodation, means to support you and your family, etc.) you should be fine.